# Cross domain ajax call: postMessage

Tags: jquery, asp.net, xss, postmessage

I searched in Google found that we can use postMessage to get the cross domain data.

But I didn't find any useful link or data.

It can be used in the messaging service. and I tried it. It works fine for messaging.

Means: I send request to certain domain and in that domain I am able to get the data.

But I don't know how it will work to fetch the data from services.

Please suggest and if possible share some code to fetch the data from other origin domain.

I don't have access to the server so that I can set the Allow_Origin to * or our site. So I have to find a way to get the data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the server you are getting data from doesn't offer the possibility for a JSONP, you have to use another server as a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

If server response is in json you can use jsonp as dataType attribute in ajax function. This will work in some occasions.

Comment: Then, using proxy should be the viable solution